# Skew a bell-shaped curve

Tags: calculus, functions, probability-distributions

Consider symmetric bell-shaped 2-dimensional functions like
$$f((x,y))=\exp(-(x^2+y^2)), \ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$

A transformation to skew $f$ in direction $-(1,1)$ is
$$\hat{f}((x,y))=\frac{f((x,y))}{1+\exp( a(x+y)+b)},$$
looking like that:

[image]

The problem is that $f$ gets elongated (green) perpendicular to the skew direction.

[image]

Is there a better transformation/method to skew without elongation? Ideas appreciated!

I thought about transforming the space like $\hat{f}=f \circ h$ for a mapping $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ but that caused elongations as well.

Comment: Is this a fair rephrasing: you want its level sets to be still (roughly) circular while having an uncentered maximum?

Comment: Yes, something like that. More like the 'Leaning Tower of Pisa' but with smooth transition to the ground.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the $f$ with
$$\begin{cases}
\exp(-2a(x^2+y^2)) & x+y <0\\
\exp(-a(x-y)^2) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
allows to skew without elongation. The level sets are fairly circular as well.
[image]

A similar transformation without separate cases is given by
$$\frac{\exp(-\sqrt{a}(x-y)^2)}{1+\exp(-a(x+y))}, \ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$$